# Show that $\lim \limits_{z\rightarrow \infty} {\frac{z^2}{z-i}}=\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Show that $$\lim \limits_{z\rightarrow \infty} {\frac{z^2}{z-i}}=\infty$$

It is so obvious that this is true but how do I show it rigorously? Would this make sense: Since $${\frac{z^2}{z-i}}=\frac{z}{1-\frac{i}{z}}$$ And $$\frac{\lim \limits_{z\rightarrow \infty}z}{\lim \limits_{z\rightarrow \infty}1-\lim \limits_{z\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{i}{z}}}=\frac{\lim \limits_{z\rightarrow \infty}z}{1}=\infty$$

Comment: Do you an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof?

Comment: We weren't told one yet...

Comment: What definition of limit are you using then?

Comment: Im not using any to be honest. We were only told the definitions of when the variable tends to some complex number. That's why I don't know what to do for this one...

Comment: @snowman: If you want to show it "rigorously" you need a definition of what $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty}f(z)=\infty$ means. (Or I guess you could apply some theorems based on a definition of what it means at least.)

Comment: @AlexR. So the bit about the limit of i/z makes sense? I was unsure about that part

Comment: Another way is adding $\frac{1}{z-i}$ to the equation and notice that $\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{1}{z-i}=0$
$$\frac{z^2+1}{z-i}=\frac{(z-i)(z+i)}{z-i}=z+i$$

Comment: You should prove that for all A > 0, there is some positive M, such that |z| > M implies |f(z)| > A. Where |.| is the "modulus" of a complex number. f(x) being the function at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(z) = z^2/(z - i)$. To find $\lim_{z\to \infty} z^2/(z - i)$, we compute $\lim_{z\to 0} f(1/z)$. Note $$f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = \dfrac{\frac{1}{z^2}}{\frac{1}{z} - i} = \frac{1}{z - iz^2}$$ Thus $$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{1}{f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)} = \lim_{z\to 0} (z - iz^2) = 0 - i0 = 0$$ Therefore $\lim_{z\to 0} f(1/z) = \infty$, which implies $\lim_{z\to \infty} f(z) = \infty$, i.e., $\lim_{z\to \infty} z^2/(z - i) = \infty$.